# Access Currently Logged In User (Via VPN) Details in Browser

Tags: javascript, iphone, authentication, ipad, windows-authentication

I have an iPad and iPhone with VPN client installed and connected to my network with user id and password.
I have to create a web application hosted within the network and when I open the url in browser n iPad or iPhone, I have to display currently logged in user detail in browser.

Is it possible? Currently I can access the application with the url but don't know what JavaScript code I need to write to get currently logged in user with VPN.

Idea is that, web application will be based on windows authentication and we don't want users to type user id and password again if they are already connoted to the network via VPN. Any other better solution is also welcomed.

If we need to install another app or client on iPad, we can consider that as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure JavaScript can't access any of this information.

Comment: Maybe the server application can communicate with the VPN server to get the user information.